# IPhone disable/hide scrubbar mpmovieplayercontroller in fullscreen mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, custom-controls, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm creating an iphone app with video clips (among other things) where I need to play one or more ads before the actual video clip. Naturally my client doesn't want users to be able to fast forward during the ads but at the same time they must be able to exit the view so I cant set controlStyle to MPMovieControlStyleNone.

I would prefer not to hack the default view and remove the scrubbar so it seems my only option is to implement a custom bar with a single "Done"/"Back" button.

I've googled my eyes out trying to find example code for this, but no dice. I've seen similar questions posted here as well but no answers are given that could help me out. I'm a novice IOS developer and could really use som help with this (custom control bar with single "Done" button for fullscreen MPMoviePlayerController that shows/hideson tap OR disable scrubbar in an acceptable fashion – in fullscreen mode).

Anyone done this before or know where to find some example code? Thanks!

Comment: I find myself in a similar position and am surprised at the lack of anything talking about even creating custom controls for a video player - did you get anywhere in the end? :)

Comment: Yes, 'twas a long time ago so I don't rememebr exactly what I did, but I used this: https://github.com/blommegard/HSPlayer and made some modifications to it; probably toggled the buttons and scrubbar depending on type of video (ad/not-ad)